# Create a Jenkins job to deploy a file on a server

Tags: linux, git, jenkins

I am working on a Jenkins job that will download a specific file from a GIT repo and then deploy it on a server to a specified location.
Jenkins job will ask below variables from the user:

1. Commit ID and name of the file in repo that needs to be copied.
2. Path on the target server where the file needs to be copied.

Here's what I have done so far:

- Installed and configured the GIT so it will pull the repo to the Jenkins server
- Configured the target servers so Jenkins can copy the file to one of the 3 target servers using 'execute shell option'.
- In the build action, wrote an ssh command that will checkout a specific commit of a file from the git repo.
- Wrote a shell command that will scp the checked out file and to the one of the 3 target servers. Of course the target server will be provided by the user.

Here's what the code looks like so far:

```
git checkout $commit $filename
scp $filename username@$servername:/path/to/deploy/
```

The challenge is how to feed the variables to the shell script.
Is it even possible to do it this way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this - https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/

Comment: Did you look at using either [SSH](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh/) or [Publish  over SSH](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/) plugins instead of "execute shell"? Both also integrate with [Credentials](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/) plugin.

Comment: I did use publish over SSH. Please check my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked.

Added the GIT repo to the Jenkins freestyle job
[image]

After checking the option, 'this project is parameterized', I added 3 variables as shown.
[image]

Then modified the shell script as below
[image]

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
ssh ansible@$server_name "cp "$File_path"/"$file_name" "$File_path"/"$file_name"_"$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")";"
scp $file_name ansible@$server_name:$File_path
```